# Java - Search using a part of key word

Tags: java

I have requirement of selecting s subset of data from a collection using a part of a key word

Assume that I have a collection consist of following entries,

```
"Pine Grosbeak"  
"House Crow"  
"Hume`s Leaf Warbler"  
"Great Northern Loon"  
"Long-tailed Duck"  
"Lapland Longspur"  
"Northern Gannet"  
"Eastern Imperial Eagle"  
"Little Auk"  
"Lesser Spotted Woodpecker"  
"Iceland Gull"
```

When I provide a search string as “ro” following should be filtered;

```
"House Crow"  
"Pine Grosbeak"
```

(This is something similar to `“LIKE  ‘%ro%’ “`  clause in SQL)

Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply do something like that:

```
for (String s : strings)
{
    if (s.contains(search))
    {
        // match
    }
}
```

And if you want to be case insensitive:

```
String lowerSearch = search.toLowerCase();  
for (String s : strings)
{
    if (s.toLowerCase().contains(lowerSearch))
    {
        // match
    }
}
```

Comment: a small doubt. does contain perform whole string search or "LIKE %ro%" of sql.according to the source code of arraylist , it doesnt.

Comment: @Suresh It does: str.contains("ro") will match "rothing", "thingro", "ro" and "crothing", for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through and use
`contains()` method to filter

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();  
lst.add("Pine Grosbeak");
lst.add("House Crow");
.
.
.
for(String str:lst){  
if(str.contains(keyword)){
System.out.println("matched : "+ str);
}
}
```